# Does the PDO_PGSQL driver support prepared statement?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I am using PosgreSQL and PDO on my projects. As is said here [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) by default PDO does not use prepared statements for database drivers which does not support it. Does the PosgreSQL database driver (PDO_PGSQL) support prepared statement? Thanks.

Comment: If a pdo driver doesn't support prepared statements, PDO will emulate them for you. See: [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: Yeh, I know that. An asking **does** PDO_PGSQL support  prepared statements, but not about PDO behavior ;)

Comment: so turn off the emulation and try to prepare a statement...

Comment: @MarcB *"It will always fall back to emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the current query."* - How exactly would you test that...? :)

Comment: with emulation turned off, preparing a statement would just fail.

Comment: @MarcB Will it really? - "It will ***always fall back*** to emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully prepare the current query."*

Answer (score 3):

PDO does not use ***native*** prepared statements by default, meaning it's emulating prepared statements internally instead of using the actually existing database API. You turn that behaviour off by setting the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false`.

> `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` Enables or disables emulation of prepared
>   statements. Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or
>   have limited support for them. Use this setting to force PDO to either
>   always emulate prepared statements (if `TRUE`), or to try to use
>   native prepared statements (if `FALSE`). It will always fall back to
>   emulating the prepared statement if the driver cannot successfully
>   prepare the current query.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

That just to (hopefully) clarify your statement.

PDO_PGSQL *does* support native prepared statements [since 0.9](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=PDO_PGSQL), which was released almost 10 years ago.

Comment: That means data is escaped and stored in placeholders in the query and then the query send (as a plan text) to the database server with no creating prepared statements?

Comment: If **emulated** prepared statements are used, then yes, the data is escaped and sent to the database as one plain query.

Comment: If emulation is disabled like this: 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false ); 
will the PDO_PGSQL driver use real prepared statements?

Comment: Yes, as far as I'm aware it will.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is that for the purpose of protecting against SQL injection it doesn't matter.

Properly implemented and consistent parameter escaping in the database driver is sufficient to offer the same level of SQL injection protection as use of server side paramaterised statements.

It'd be nice if PDO used PostgreSQL's bind-parse-execute protocol to let the server handle parameterised statements, but it's far from vital to do so.

The purpose of advising people to use parameterised statements (often inaccurately called "prepared statements") is to make sure they're consistent with how they construct statements. If all escaping goes through a single entrypoint with a properly written framework and you follow strict rules about using that framework then you're much less likely to leave accidental SQL injection holes.

You actually want PDO to do its parameterised statement emulation for non-DML/SELECT statements, because PostgreSQL's wire protocol doesn't support parameter binding for DDL.